# Reference two separate DataFrames in SparkR operations

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am trying to split a DataFrame (DF), `B` into two distinct (by row) subsets. I first `sample` the DF to produce a new DF that includes approx. half of the rows from `B`. Then, I try to `filter` on the DF with the condition that this new DF, `b2` includes every row of `B` with `z` values that are *not equal* to the `z` values included in `b1`.

This seems like it should be fairly straightforward. However, the `filter` expression just results in an empty DataFrame. Am I misunderstanding the syntax for `filter`, or can you simply not refer to distinct DataFrames in SparkR operations?

```
w <- rbind(3, 0, 2, 3, NA, 1)
z <- rbind("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

d2 <- cbind.data.frame(w, z)
B <- as.DataFrame(sqlContext, d2)

b1 <- sample(B, FALSE, 0.5)
b2 <- filter(B, B$z != b1$z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually two different problems here:

- In general you cannot reference another table inside filter without performing some type of `join` operation first.
- In this particular, due to common lineage, this construct a trivially true equality (it is similar issue to [SPARK-6231](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6459)), hence no exception but empty result set.

Since as for now (Spark 1.6) SparkR doesn't provide `randomSplit` you can apply split manually

```
seed <- stats::runif(1)
b <- B %>% withColumn("rand", rand(seed))
b1 <- b %>% where(b$rand <= 0.5)
b2 <- b %>% where(b$rand > 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

SparkR offers a set of functions built on Spark SQL that provide useful data manipulation abilities.  A way of achieving this is with the SparkR except() command (think of it like an != join in SQL):

```
w <- rbind(3, 0, 2, 3, NA, 1)
z <- rbind("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

d2 <- cbind.data.frame(w, z)
B <- as.DataFrame(sqlContext, d2)

b1 <- sample(B, FALSE, 0.5)
b2 <- except(B, b1)
```

Comment: Problem with `except` is that it requires a full shuffle which makes it way to expensive for sampling.

Comment: thanks @zero323 ... thanks for the insight.  These nuggets are really hard to find for people converting from R to SparkR.  Particularly as most of us are trying to learn SparkR with small data set examples ... it's hard to know what's the right way to use SparkR when you do use it for the large data sets it's designed for.  I suspect the right answer on creating test/train sets with big data is to take two relatively small samples rather than partitioning the full data set.